# How do I enable dual monitor support in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have been trying to extend my display across 2 monitors in Windows 8.

The key on my laptop, which performs that function doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to refer to **[cnet's detailed description](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57541476-285/run-windows-8-desktop-on-a-second-monitor/)** of the process here, you will find everything you need.

Try a <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the options to extend display.
If you are presented with the following error, **(re)install your GPU drivers**.

[image: Error]